# cookie confusion with session storage

Tags: node.js, cookies, express-session

I am using the following Node.js code to create a 'session store' to keep user information.  These text files are kept in a folder called "session-store":

```
 var session = require('express-session');
 var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);

 app.use(session({
  store: new FileStore({path: './session-store'}),
 // using FileStore with express-session
 // as the store method, replacing the default memory store
  secret: 'secret_key',
  name: 'myadmin',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: { maxAge: 60000, httpOnly: true, secure: false }  
 }));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 if (req.session.views) {
  req.session.views++;
 } else {
  req.session.views = 1;
 } 
});
```

My text file which contains the session information seems to generate properly.  However I have some confusion regarding its proper usage.  In my cookie (.txt) file, it reports the "views" correctly, such as ""views":1".  However if I define another variable, such as "req.session.broadcast = String(req.body.usr);" I do not see this information in my text file...why would this not be inclusive?  Is this because the .txt file containing the cookie session storage information is generated only on the initial 'route' (i.e. the "app.get('/', function (req, res) {...do stuff}") and no other place in the Node.js code?  (NOTE:  I have "req.session.broadcast" set in a different route other than the 'homepage' route...which I guess is when the cookie file gets generated...possibly?).

I am simply attempting to properly manage users...therefore I want to be able to have certain session variables properly set and tracked for each unique user browser.

Are the "req.session.user" and/or req.session variable(s) 'hard coded' variables?  I believe they get set when the browser is directed at the webpage, however how can they be used to terminate a session?  Do they automatically become null if the user closes their browser (using the "x" in the right top corner) OR if the user directs their browser to another webpage...?

Any help with these questions and any other advice would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: When the user closes their browser it does not change the session variables on your server. You need a system to delete session variables after a certain amount of time.

Comment: Where do you put the `req.session.broadcast = String(req.body.usr);` statement?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The req.session.broadcast is defined in another route...for example app.get('/logins', function (req, res) {...do stuff}  ...I assume this may be why it does not get reported in my .txt file...?  In other words the .txt file only generates upon execution of the app.get('/', function (req, res) {...do stuff} route when the webpage is first accessed...correct?

Comment: How can I test to determine if the user has closed the browser or gone to another webpage?  Does the req.session.user and/or req.session become "undefined" automatically at that point...or is there another way to determine if the user is still within the website?  I would probably like to delete the session storage variables on the server at that point...so as to ensure when a user is 'active' and when they are gone...possible?

Comment: With a basic session there is no way for the server to know if the user has closed the browser. However, when the user closes the browser it should destroy the session cookie. So, if the user then reopens the browser and connects to the same server it will not present a cookie to the server. The server will then send a new (different) cookie to the browser so a new session is initiated. req.session only exists in your server program when it runs so it will not persist. You still have the session data in your file store and (I think) you need some mechanism to clear this eventually.

Comment: Thank you...is there some way to know when the browser has been closed/redirected so then I can trigger a mechanism to clear the session store and perform any variable 'cleanup' that is required server side...?  Is there any code I can reference someplace?  Would I have to write a routine to check if 'req.session.user' and/or 're.session' is defined or is instead undefined...?

Comment: I am definitely a beginner in this field so may be wrong but I think you do need a routine to delete old session information in your session store. I was looking at CRON jobs for doing this on a daily basis but I did not do it. Sorry not to be more helpful.

Comment: thanks.  I guess we are in the same situation.  I suppose reading the text file and deleting the appropriate entries is do-able...my more immediate challenge is to be able to determine when the user has navigated away from the website or closed the browser...there must be some sort of way to registre a 'trigger' for those events...then it would be a matter of figuring how to adjust the session store.

Comment: There may be some front end approach but I think it is possible to handle it all from the backend. Good luck....

Comment: thanks for your time and the responses.